# How to delete a file to the trash in BASH (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash

I've looked everywhere for the answer, but I can't find it.

Is it possible to move/delete a file to the trash folder on linux. But also having the trashinfo file.

E.g I can move the file into the trash folder fine, but I don't have the trashinfo file.

tldr; How to delete a file to trash in BASH

Comment: Trash is implementation-specific. You need to tell us which environment you are using. Gnome ? KDE ? Other ?

Comment: better place to ask:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ÁppleAssassin Are you using the default environment of Ubuntu 12.10, aka Gnome with Unity ?

Answer (score 8):

In Ubuntu the trash files are kept in `~/.local/share/Trash/files`

There is a [trash command line interface](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli) that you can use. To install do:

```
sudo apt-get install trash-cli
```

Then, to trash something do:

```
trash-put myfile.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately with that, I still don't have the trashinfo file which keeps the files original location, if I wanted to restore it

Comment: I have updated my answer with a better solution.

Comment: And it's a good thing to `alias rm=trash-put` so you don't forget. I think `trash` is designed to be as `rm` compatible as it can.

Comment: I was thinking on making an `alias trash="mv $# ~/.local/Trash/files/."`, but since the arguments aren't being reversed I think **the best solution is this one ;)**

Answer (score 0):

Easy...

```
mv filename /home/username/.local/Trash/files
```

Comment: _E.g I can move the file into the trash folder fine, but I don't have the trashinfo file._

Comment: You need to write a little script that will create the trashinfo file. You can see the format of what should be in the file by opening it.For full instructions see http://xyzhou.com/linux/lv1-linux/make-your-rm-command-in-bash-works-with-trash-in-gnome-to-protect-accidental-deletion.html

Comment: I am aware of that. I just wanted to tell you that you'd need to improve your answer because otherwise it doesn't give any new information to the OP.